# N-dimensional optimization of moments of distribution function

Tags: optimization, probability, discrete-optimization

Let's say I have a bag of marbles. Each marble has several attributes (color, diameter, surface roughness, weight).

I know that there is a statistical relationship between various marble attributes and weight. I am trying to optimize for the weight distribution (either maximize/minimize the mean or the variance) by only making cuts in the other parameters (e.g., pick colors and range of diameters to achieve the desired result). The cuts can be single-ended (e.g., `diameter > x` or `diameter < y`; need not be between `x` and `y`, but that's a bonus).

I don't have analytic closed-form equations. Instead, I have a large number of discrete samples. I can calculate the weight distribution numerically for the entire population, or for a sub-population based on pre-specified cuts.

Mathematically, the weight distribution $w$ can be thought of as a joint PDF of the form:

$$f_w = f(w,x_0,x_1,...x_n)$$

Where $w$ is the weight of the marble, and $x_0 ... x_n$ are other attributes. Find $x_{0,A}, x_{0,B} ... x_{1,A},x_{1,B}$ such that the following moment sum is minimized (for example, to minimize the mean weight):

$$\min\left( \sum \limits_{w} w \sum \limits_{x_0 = x_{0,A}}^{x_{0,B}} ... \sum \limits_{x_n = x_{n,A}}^{x_{n,B}} f(w,x_0,x_1,...x_n) \right)$$

The brute-force method involves picking values of $x_{0,A}, x_{0,B} ... x_{n,A},x_{n,B}$ and computing the moment sum of interest until the optimum value is found. This matrix-calculation involves overlapping subproblems. In two or three dimensions (2 or 3 parameters), it is straightforward to avoid the overlap (e.g., by using prefix sums/weighted sums). This technique gets unwieldy for N-dimensions.

**Is there a well-known algorithm or group of algorithms that can achieve this?**

**EDIT: August 26, 2020**

The function f is constructed from a fixed number of prescribed samples that are available before the calculation begins. A number of bins and/or bin sizes are selected for each of the parameters ($w$, $x_0$ ... $x_n$) available. An ($n+1$)-dimensional matrix is created (based on the selected bin/size) and the count for `f[w][x0]...[xn]` is incremented as each sample is processed to build the joint PDF (a normalization constant is retained separately).

For single-ended cuts, one can compute cumulative sums (even weighted cumulative sums, per above) starting from either low or high indices to the maximum index for each dimension. For example, starting at low indices and working our way up in a cumulative fashion, we are inherently making cuts at each iteration where we only retain values of `x_i` less than some value (where `i` is the dimension or `i`$^{th}$ parameter which runs from `0` to `n`).

For two parameters (two dimensions) `f` becomes a matrix. The fastest way to implement the computation is to use a dynamic programming approach, where a separate matrix `x` is kept. For each element of `x`, we compute the cumulative sum corresponding to the same indices of `f`.
So in two dimensions, the computation becomes `x[i][j] = x[i-1][j] + x[i][j-1] - x[i-1][j-1] + f[i][j]`.  As the iteration proceeds, on can keep track of the maximum or minimum value of the sum over `f` for a given cut (indices `i` and `j`). Reversing the traversal order of the indices allows single-ended cuts in the other direction ("four corners" are possible with 2 parameters, with cuts below or above certain values for each of the parameters).

I've derived a formula that extends the above to four dimensions, which now involves 16 terms (not a trivial task). I'm looking for a generalization to N dimensions, or an alternative approach.

Comment: Are the objective function evaluations noise-free? Please describe in detail how the objective function is evaluated. Are the discrete samples computable "on demand"?

Comment: @MarkL.Stone The objective function evals are noise-free (by that I assume you mean same exact result if computed multiple times). The discrete samples are all available in advance; (offline algorithm is fine). I assume you're familiar with the 2D (matrix) problem, where each cell is of the matrix X is the cumulative 2D sum of some source matrix A; the computational shortcut is X[i,j] = X[i-1,j] + X[i,j-1] - X[i-1,j-1] + A[i,j].  I've managed to extend this to 4 dimensions, allowing me to make quick cuts (single-ended) once the matrix is computed.  I'd like to go to higher dims...

Comment: I suggest you edit your question and write ths all out, in yet more detail (self-contained).